# Change page content after submitting form

Tags: php, html, forms

so I googled my question but haven't found the answer.

I have a page with a form. The form is really simple, customer needs to enter his name and phone number. After submitting the form my controller sends customer's name and phone number via email.
After the form is submitted, on the page appears "Your message has been successfully sent!" message, but it appears on top of the page, and some .css style are overwritten.

So, how do I totally clear the page's content after sumbitting, and fill the page with another content?
The form

```
<form action="<?php echo $action; ?>" method="post" name="orderForm">
    <input type="hidden" name="product_model" value="<?php echo $product_model; ?>">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="right">Ваше имя:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="your_name"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="right">Номер телефона:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="left"><input type="submit" value="ЗАКАЗАТЬ"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Controller

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonOrderForm extends Controller {
    public function index() {
        $this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_title'));
        $this->document->setDescription($this->config->get('config_meta_description'));
        $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('common/orderForm');
        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->config->get('config_title');

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/orderForm.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/orderForm.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/common/orderForm.tpl';
        }


        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());

        /* Check if form has been submitted */
        if( isset($_POST['your_name']) )
        {
            /* Input data check */
            $your_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["your_name"]);
            $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
            $product_model = htmlspecialchars($_POST["product_model"]);
            /* Set the e-mail recipient */
            $myemail = "imakenza@yandex.ru";
            /* Create a new variable by assigning a value to it */
            $message_to_myemail = "Хозяин, тут заказ пришел.";
            /* Send a message using the mail () function */
            $from  = "Имя клиента: $your_name \r\nТелефон клиента: $email \r\n Модель продукта: $product_model \r\n";
            mail($myemail, $message_to_myemail, $from);
            ?>
            <p>Your message has been successfully sent!</p>
        <?php
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say controller, you mean MVC pattern. **Do not make HTML output in your controller !**

Also, your problem here is that you ask for output your form and then display the message :

```
 $this->response->setOutput($this->render());

        /* Check if form has been submitted */
        if( isset($_POST['your_name']) )
        {
            /* Input data check */
            $your_name = htmlspecia
            ...
```

Do it this way :

```
    /* Check if form has been submitted */
    if( !isset($_POST['your_name']) )
    {
            $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    else
    {
        //$your_name = htmlspecia
        //call an other template here !
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are always rendering the form from the controller. If you want it to only show the message and not the form on submit then you just need to not render the form if isset($_POST['your_name']). Like so:

```
<?php
class ControllerCommonOrderForm extends Controller {
public function index() {
    $this->document->setTitle($this->config->get('config_title'));
    $this->document->setDescription($this->config->get('config_meta_description'));
    $this->data['action'] = $this->url->link('common/orderForm');
    $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->config->get('config_title');

    if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/orderForm.tpl')) {
        $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/common/orderForm.tpl';
    } else {
        $this->template = 'default/template/common/orderForm.tpl';
    }




    /* Check if form has been submitted */
    if( isset($_POST['your_name']) )
    {
        /* Input data check */
        $your_name = htmlspecialchars($_POST["your_name"]);
        $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST["email"]);
        $product_model = htmlspecialchars($_POST["product_model"]);
        /* Set the e-mail recipient */
        $myemail = "imakenza@yandex.ru";
        /* Create a new variable by assigning a value to it */
        $message_to_myemail = "Хозяин, тут заказ пришел.";
        /* Send a message using the mail () function */
        $from  = "Имя клиента: $your_name \r\nТелефон клиента: $email \r\n Модель продукта: $product_model \r\n";
        mail($myemail, $message_to_myemail, $from);
        ?>
        <p>Your message has been successfully sent!</p>
    } else {
        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());
    }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: I agree with @OlivierH. You shouldn't just display text normally like that though. Render a sent template rather. The above method will work as a quick fix though